# Restarting Travis CI build using new defaults

Tags: python, travis-ci

I have a PR build that's failed and another build that's passed successfully.  The only difference between them is one is running in Ubuntu "trusty" and the other in "precise".  I think when this PR was submitted the default was "precise" but the new default is "trusty".  If I try to restart the build it seem to retain the old default even though it's not specified in ".travis.yml".

Is there a way to restart a build and have it use the latest config defaults?  Specifically, the failed build reports "precise" as the distribution used in the "View config", but it's not being explicitly set and the new default should be "trusty".  A "restart" doesn't change the config.